# Generating a PKCS12 key from SecKeyRef on iOS

Tags: ios, security, rsa, watchkit, keychain

I'm working on a problem where I need to share a public/private keypair from an iOS app to a Watchkit 2.0 app.  Since Watchkit 2.0 no longer allows you to access the keychain on the phone from the watch directly, I want to send a PEM public key, and a PKCS12 private key to the Watch over the connection, and import it into the Watch's keychain.  This is made difficult for a few reasons:

1. SecItemExport is not available on iOS anymore. (Not even in the headers, I'm on iOS 9)
2. The options to get the bytes from the SecItemCopyMatching are not in an immediately useable format (and not something I can just shove into an NSData and send over the wire to the watch).

We are generating 
Using the very helpful code from this website (http://blog.wingsofhermes.org/?p=42) I was able to get the public key bytes into a PEM format.

I'm looking for a similar transformation for the private key bytes to PKCS12 that can be used by SecPKCS12Import.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenSSL `PKCS12_create` function to create a `PKCS12` structure and write it to file using `i2d_PKCS12_bio` function.

`PKCS12_create` takes the certificate, private key, passphrase, chain of CA certificates and other parameter.

It is explained in a pretty well manner in [documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS12_create.html).